# Как получить файлы из текущего jar

Tags: java

Как с помощью java получить File которые находятся в директории, а директория находится в собственном jar?
Вот как я получаю ссылки

```
URL defaultTheme = Object.class.getClass().getResource(File.separator.concat("sound").concat(File.separator).concat("Default"));
URL ubuntuTheme = Object.class.getClass().getResource(File.separator.concat("sound").concat(File.separator).concat("Ubuntu"));


File defaultThemeFile = new File(defaultTheme.getPath());
File ubuntuThemeFile = new File(ubuntuTheme.getPath());
```

Пробую получить список файлов через `File[] fil = defaultThemeFile.listFiles();`
Но всегда `fil` равен `null`. И чтобы работало на операционных системах `Linux and Windows`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно получить файл как массив байтов.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final int BUFFER = 2048;
    final String MY_DIR = "META-INF/";
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("c:\\MyJar.jar");
    ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(inputStream);
    ZipEntry e = null;
    while (null != (e = zip.getNextEntry())) {
        if (e.getName().startsWith(MY_DIR) && !e.isDirectory()) {
            int count;
            byte data[] = new byte[BUFFER];
            while ((count = zip.read(data, 0, BUFFER)) != -1) {
                System.out.println("Filename: " + e.getName() + " File in bytes: " + data);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться новым api [`java.nio.file`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/package-summary.html), т.к. есть реализация `FileSystemProvider` для zip-файлов.

Для работы нужно получить адрес jar-файла примерно такого вида: `jar:file:/E:/eclipse-workspace/sandbox/sandbox.jar`. Для текущего класса нужный `URI` можно получить вызовом:

```
URI uri = getClass().getResource( getClass().getSimpleName() + ".class" ).toURI();
// проверяем, что ресурс в jar
if ( !"jar".equalsIgnoreCase( uri.getScheme() ) ) {
    System.out.println( "Source is not in a jar file!" );
    return;
}
```

Дальше с помощью этого `URI` нужно получить объект `FileSystem` и работать с ним с помощью нового api:

```
try (FileSystem fs = FileSystems.newFileSystem( uri, Collections.emptyMap() )) {
    // вывести список элементов в корне архива
    Files.list( fs.getPath("/") ).forEach( System.out::println );

    // создать Path для файла /sound/test.txt
    final Path path = fs.getPath( "/sound/test.txt" );

    // прочитать файл в список строк
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines( path );

    // получение InputStream
    InputStream is = Files.newInputStream( fs.getPath( "/sound/somesound.wav" ) );
}
```